# Octave: Writing vector function without looping over index

Tags: octave, vectorization

How do i implement, without specifying each component separately (as shown below), or by looping over index, a function like:

```
function h = f(a)
    h(1) = a(2)*a(3)/a(1);
    h(2) = a(3)*a(1)/a(2);
    h(3) = a(1)*a(2)/a(3);
endfunction
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that in all cases expressions can be rewritten as `a(1)*a(2)*...*a(n)/a(i)^2`, We obtain the following:

```
function h = f(a)
    for i=1:length(a)
        h(i) = prod(a)/a(i)^2;
    endfor
endfunction
```

Another solution:

```
function h = f(a)
  h = prod(a)./a.^2;
endfunction
```

Comment: +1 for the `Another solution` part. That worked. I didn't want to loop over indices (your first solution), the question specifies this. Though I didn't emphasize that enough.